# Trusted Entities in the AWS IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a cross account role which gives some permissions to two lambda functions from another account. Recently I noticed my cross account role trusted entities keep getting modified (the lambda roles ARNs been removed from the trusted entities and I had to add them back). I'm not seeing any event in the cloudtrail related to this change! So I talked to the other account administrator and I figured they been removing and recreating those two lambdas sometimes. So I assume AWS IAM would remove the trusted entity ARN from my role if the entity doesn't exist anymore. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: I don't think AWS IAM is removing the policy.  So another option to track what is happening is to use AWS Config which show when role is changed.  The other nice thing with Config is will link to the associated CloudTrail Event.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen an ARN be recreated like that.  Seems like a bug in the service?